# Discriminant of a polynomial modulo a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> If $p$ is a prime and divides the discriminant of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ why is then $disc(f(x)\bmod p)=0$?

I know that the discriminant is a combination of the coefficients of $f(x)$. I.e. $disc(f(x))=k_0\cdot a_0^{j_0}+k_2\cdot a_1^{j_1}+...+k_{n-1}\cdot a_{n-1}^{j_{n-1}}, k_i\in \mathbb{Z}$.
So if $p|disc(f(x))\Rightarrow p|k_i$ or $p|a_i^{j_i}, \forall i \in\{0,...,n-1\}$
If $p|a_i, \forall i$ we are done. But what if it just divides the $k_i$'s?

I would be really glad for any help.

Thank you already in advance.

---

Edit: Is it possible that I can argue that $disc(f)=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2} \Pi_{i=1}^n f'(\alpha_i)$, where the $\alpha_i$'s are the roots of $f$ over a splitting field. I.e. if p divides the discriminant of $f$, p must divide some $f'(\alpha_i)$ and therefore it certainly divides $\bar{f}'(\alpha_i)$, where $\bar f := f \mod p$. Therefore the hole product $\Pi_i \bar{f}(\alpha_i)=0 \mod p$. Which implies that $disc(f \mod p)=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2} \Pi_i \bar{f}(\alpha_i)=0 \mod p$

Is this right?

Comment: Is "$f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$" a type-o for "$f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$"? How would "$p|\text{disc}(f(x))\Rightarrow\forall i\ (p|k_i\vee p|a_i^{j_1})$" hold, or even "$f(x) \text{ mod }p$" make sense, if not?

Comment: Where did I write that $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: user26857 corrected it.

Comment: Ah ups. Ok. Well then it was a typo... Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant is a polynomial in the coefficients of $f(x)$. And as reduction mod $p$ is a homomorphism we have that $disc(f(x))=disc(\overline{f}(x)) \mod p$. and as $p$ divides $disc(f(x))$, we have $disc(\overline{f}(x))=disc(f(x))=0 \mod p$

($\overline{f}(x)$ is my notation for the reduction mod $p$)